# htaccess replace -{dynamic_id}.html to _i{dynamic_id}

Tags: .htaccess

Need some help with htaccess.
Have a lot of dynamic urls:
example /folder1/folder2/slug-text-234556.html -
how to replace -234556.html -> _i234556 and redirect 301 to /folder1/folder2/slug-text_i234556 ?

Comment: I suggest you hire a coder. SO is NOT a free code writing service.

Comment: @arkascha you wanna say it's not possible using .htaccess configurations?

Comment: I never said such thing. Certainly not. What I said is that StackOverflow is not a free coding service that does your work for you, as you apparently think. StackOverflow is a place that offers help to people who actually code themselves, try to solve their tasks themselves and who got stuck in a specific detail of their code which they cannot resolve. It is expected from those asking that they show their own code, what they tried and that they explain _in detail_ what _exactly_ the specific issue is. That is all explained in the introduction to this site which I am sure you read...

Comment: @arkascha. I'm a developer (php) but i'm not good at htaccess. So i just asked to the community maybe some one faced to the similar challenge and can write solution or some tips how to solve. I spent many hours in google to find solution before write here. And i'm definitely not looking for someone who will do my work for me.

Comment: The trick is not so much to google endlessly. Google does not teach, google does not differ between helpful and idiotic content. You should look at a simple tutorial (which you can indeed find on google) and, much more helpful actually, the documentation of the rewriting module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html  It is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague and the comments did not exactly help to get you to reveal more of what you actually tried, so I have to go with a "long shot" here:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?(.+)-(\d+)\.html$ /$1_i$2 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)_i(\d+)/?$ /$1-$2.html [END]
```

That rule set will *redirect* requests to `/.....-<number>.html` to `/....._i<number>` (which is what you actually ask) and it *rewrites* requests in the opposite way. I assume that is what you are looking for.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

The important thing for you will be to actually understand those rules. Only then will you be able to adjust them to your needs which will be necessary now or later with absolute certainty.